# Cannot resolve locationclient

Tags: android

Android Location Client cannot resolve

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {
    private LocationClient locationClient;
    private LocationRequest locationRequest;
    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        locationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);

        locationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                  .setInterval(5000)
                  .setFastestInterval(500)
                  .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

        SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        googleMap = supportMapFragment.getMap();
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);   
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        HaritadaKonumGosterAsyncTask task = new HaritadaKonumGosterAsyncTask();
        task.execute(new Location[] {location});
    }
        @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        locationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {}

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {}

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        locationClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if(locationClient.isConnected())
            locationClient.removeLocationUpdates(this);

        locationClient.disconnect();
    }

    private class HaritadaKonumGosterAsyncTask  extends AsyncTask<Location, Void, LatLng> {

        @Override
        protected LatLng doInBackground(Location... params) {
            Location konum = params[0];
            return new LatLng(konum.getLatitude(), konum.getLongitude());
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(LatLng konum) {
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(konum, 15));
        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your **build.gradle** add following code

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
```

More details refer [Setting Up Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)

Comment: thank you for your help.Can you send me new api code.for location

Comment: i already use  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'